# Why IP address for Linux Bridge which is layer 2 virtual device?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

Shouldn't bridge (or a switch) be working without having an IP address? I believe I can have a bridge `br0` setup with `eth0` and `eth1` as members both having no IP addresses.

I can't understand why an address should be allocated to `br0`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A bridge does not need an IP address to function. Without one it will just perform layer 2 switching, spanning tree protocol and filtering (if configured).

An IP address is required if you want your bridge to take part in layer 3 routing of IP packets.

As an example you can setup a bridge without an IP address in Debian/Ubuntu using the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
         bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

Comment: Second sentence answers my question. Remove the remaining part and I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: I am a little reluctant to trim all but the 2nd sentance. The first sentence answers the first line of your question. Admittedly the way to setup an IP-less interface on Debian/Ubuntu is only mildly related to your question so that could likely be deleted if considered too off-topic.

Comment: Does this mean if the interfaces on the bridge want to access host network or the internet, then the bridge must have an IP address?  So effectively this turns the bridge into a layer 3 device (like a router)?